# Reimplementing enumerate() to produce a sequence or iterator

Tags: python, iterator

Apparently it is possible to implement `enumerate` so it produces a sequence when given a sequence, and produces an iterable otherwise. Sequence can be safely `reversed`. This works by replacing the builtin function. Other similar functions could be made this way, too.

```
class EnumeratedSequence:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return (index,self.items[index])

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.items)

def enumerate(items):
    if hasattr(items, '__getitem__'):
        print 'Sequence detected'
        return EnumeratedSequence(items)
    else:
        print 'Iterator detected'
        return __builtin__.enumerate(items)

print list(reversed(enumerate('abcdef')))
print list(enumerate(reversed('abcdef')))
```

Which outputs:

```
Sequence detected
[(5, 'f'), (4, 'e'), (3, 'd'), (2, 'c'), (1, 'b'), (0, 'a')]
Iterator detected
[(0, 'f'), (1, 'e'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'b'), (5, 'a')]
```

This was a [solution to a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995930/typeerror-argument-to-reversed-must-be-a-sequence) of reversed(enumerate(...)) failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In `enumerate`, the test:

   ```
   hasattr(items, '__getitem__')
   ```

   isn't quite right: you need `__len__` as well as `__getitem__`. The intention would be clearer if you wrote the test like this:

   ```
   isinstance(items, Sequence)
   ```

   using [`collections.abc.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence).
2. If you're going to create a sequence, then you should implement the whole sequence interface, including [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__), [`__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__), [`__reversed__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__), `index` and `count`. This is most easily done by inheriting from [`collections.abc.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence), which provides implementations for all of these in terms of `__getitem__` and `__len__`. However, you have the opportunity to do better that this, by providing \$O(1)\$ implementations of `__contains__`, `index`, and `count`. Here's an example of how to do this for `__contains__`:

   ```
   def __contains__(self, item):
       if not isinstance(item, tuple) or len(item) != 2:
           return False
       try:
           value = self.items[item[0]]
       except IndexError:
           return False
       return value == item[1]
   ```

Answer (score 3):

First of, depending on the implementations, `__builtin__` may not be directly available (it seems to be in IPyton, but not in CPython). You should [`import __builtin__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) beforehand so `__builtin__` will always be in the global namespace. CPython implementation also have `__builtins__` (with an **s**) directly available without imports.

Second, you should remove the `print` statements in `enumerate`. I guess it was for demonstrations purposes but if you want to use that in real code it will be pure noise.

Other than that, I’d just add a docstring to `enumerate` to explain the new behavior.

However, since you are using Python 2, you can take advantage of some features that were removed in Python 3. Namely the difference between `zip` and `itertools.izip`. The former returns a list, the latter an iterator: pretty much what you’re after. And since enumerate is somewhat equivalent to zipping `itertools.count` with its parameters, it is very simple to achieve what you’re looking for:

```
from itertools import count, izip

def enumerate(iterable):
    zip_ = zip if hasattr(iterable, '__getattr__') else izip
    return zip_(count(), iterable)
```

Comment: If zip returns a list (not a sequence) then it is too greedy, it should work in constant memory and constant time.

Comment: @ArekBulski Using a trailing underscore is a convention in python when you want to use a keyword as variable name. Here `zip` is not a keyword but using `zip = zip if ...` is asking for trouble. You can always use `my_zip` or similar in your code but I personally don't like it. You can even use a one-liner to remove the variable name: `return (zip if hasattr(iterable, '__getattr__') else izip)(count(), iterable)`.

Comment: Yes, oneliner is so more readable now... ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 1):

Normally, sequences support negative indecies but I think it would be more appropriate to limit the sequences here:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    if not 0 <= index < len(self.items):
        raise IndexError('EnumeratedSequence only supports indecies [0..len).')
    return (index,self.items[index])
```